# Generate multiple SQL scripts for data backup

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a big database(`60GB`) and I want to generate Multiple SQL script for database back up.

In stackOverFlow we discussed this here -  [Get .sql file from SQL Server 2012 database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15735722/1080354)

Can we generate multiple sequential SQL files for data.I want to create around 20 sql sequential scripts each with around 3 GB data.

Is it possible either by `t-sql` query or from SQL server options?

Comment: Why would you want to do this instead of just making a backup?

Comment: I think query will help lot more to use in packages or other, compared to that GUI process....

Comment: Of course you can create it, but sounds that you're doing something wrong. Why not just normal backup or text file with bcp?

Comment: i will use batch to restore the db. also non i have few non IT friends who is comfortable just run the script and execute it. i already know how to make the normal back. so any help with the query for multiple sequential SQL files for data will be highly appreciated.